# adding signs in front of an element in the list

Tags: python, list

I have a function that returns a list:

```
a = [1,2,-3,-4,0,4,0,-2]
```

Is there a way we can add '+' sign in front of non negative values in the list?

Comment: why would you want to do that ?

Comment: just curious if we can do that..that's all

Comment: I dont think it is a good idea. `+4` is a string. and you can not do the integer manipulations without some additional processing.

Comment: @ karthikr-the list is a string..that's the reason I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the `repr` and `str` reprsentation of the integers then you can subclass `int`:

```
class Myint(int):
    def __repr__(self):
        if self > 0:
            return '+{}'.format(self)
        else:
            return '{}'.format(self)

    #similarly override `__str__` as well
...         
>>> a = [Myint(x) for x in (1,2,-3,-4,0,4,0,-2)]
>>> a
[+1, +2, -3, -4, 0, +4, 0, -2]
>>> a[0]
+1
```